# lsystem: how to scale the copied object

Tags: python

I want to copy an object that I import as .glb and copy it in different places and scale it. I was trying to use the s (scale) but that doesn't work on the object itself.

```
exec = exec.Exec()
exec.set_axiom("ff~(Cube)s(0.1)")
exec.exec()
```

I was also trying to use "Set radius" (¤) or "Decrement the diameter of segments" (!) with no effect. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you using this add-on? https://github.com/krljg/lsystem

Comment: Yes, I was trying it on blender 2.9 and 3.2

Comment: I saw in the code that the object scaled is not implemented. I changed the code a bit and added a warping to the next copied object. Pending merge request